# uninitialized constant UrlsController::Url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, coming from Java and Playframework.

I'm following a tutorial `http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/`

I am getting an error on the line `@shortened_url = Url.new`

The error is :

```
NameError in UrlsController#new
uninitialized constant UrlsController::Url
```

I feel this is something like a ClassNotFoundError in Java ?? not sure ... does anyone know what I have to do. Is it basically a matter of using `include` or `require`, with the correct reference.

Apologies for the total newb question but I find it much easier to learn by doing and making mistakes, it sticks - and I reckon others will benefit too.

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @shortened_url = Url.new
  end

  def create
    @shortened_url = Url.new(params[:url])
    if @shortened_url.save
      flash[:shortened_id] = @shortened_url.id
      redirect_to new_url_url
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @shortened_url = Url.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @shortened_url.url
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you have `Url` class? Where is the file with `Url` class source located? And what's is this file name?

Comment: Add `require 'uri'` somewhere before call to `Url#new`.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, that didn't work - although to me it sounds like it should

Comment: @MarekLipka I don't have a Url class, I was thinking that it must be 'built-in' to ROR, and I just have to reference it somehow

Comment: @Ankur nope, it isn't. Plus, like Max wrote, `Url` is reserved.

Comment: @Mareklipka thanks - using something other than Url gave different errors. I'll keep working through the issues.

Comment: How do you want to use the model (class) you didn't define?

Comment: @MarekLipka you're right. I made the Url class ... but got a different error. I was moving too fast, I need to step back and do some more reading methinks

Answer (score 6):

May or may not be the issue you're having, but `Url` is a reserved word in Rails.

Source: http://bparanj.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/reserved-words-in-rails.html

Alternatively, it's weird that calling `Url.new` is calling `new` on your `UrlsController` instead of the `Url` model. This backs up my idea about using reserved words, it can often cause strange behaviour.

Edit: Oh and it looks like from another comment that you don't have a `Url` model. You'll need one of those before you can called `.new` on it. That said, don't create a model called `Url`, the reserved word thing will probably come back to bite you.

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is trying to use the Url class/functionality in ROR - but really have no idea

Comment: I see what you mean about it being wierd, maybe I should try a different tutorial

Comment: Thanks @Max ... I guess I should do more reading, was being a bit overambitious. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) Stick with it, Rails is great!